# Finding OpenCV Paths in ROS Builds

Tags: ros, opencv, face-detection, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short version: How do I find the path to `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` provided by opencv?

Long version:
I'm working on getting the `face_detector` package to work in noetic. In the past, the path to the classifier has been hardcoded, but in noetic, since the build has to work on Ubuntu and Debian, the hardcode isn't cutting it. My failing PR is here: https://github.com/wg-perception/people/pull/88

I feel like there should be some environment variable like `$OPENCV_SHARED_DATA_DIR` but I can't find a good resource on what that would be. How can I configure my launch/param/source code to find this file on both Ubuntu and Debian?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369316/finding-opencv-paths-in-ros-builds/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2021-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Debian package `libopencv-dev` installs a cmake project config file. It sets CMake variables after `find(OpenCV)` is called.

```
$ dpkg -L libopencv-dev | grep cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules-release.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVModules.cmake
```

Have a look inside the main one

```
$ vim /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/opencv4/OpenCVConfig.cmake
```

A CMake variable that looks interesting is `OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH`.

```
#    Advanced variables:
#      - OpenCV_SHARED                   : Use OpenCV as shared library
#      - OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH             : OpenCV location
#      - OpenCV_LIB_COMPONENTS           : Present OpenCV modules list
#      - OpenCV_USE_MANGLED_PATHS        : Mangled OpenCV path flag
```

On Ubuntu Focal with OpenCV4 it resolves to `/usr/`, so one might think the path to the classifier is

```
${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/share/opencv4/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
```

However, [Debian Buster with OpenCV 3.2 it's a different path](https://packages.debian.org/buster/all/opencv-data/filelist)

```
/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
```

It looks like just the directory in `share` is different. That [should be solvable with `file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob)

```
file(GLOB haarcascade_file_path "${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/share/*/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
```

Then you can use [CMake configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/configure_file.html) to generate `classifier.yaml` from a new `classifier.yaml.in` file

```
 classifier_filename: ${haarcascade_file_path}
```

and the CMake

```
configure_file(classifier.yaml.in classifier.yaml)
```

The generated file is in [CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html#variable:CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR), so you'll need to install it to the `param` folder from the build folder

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/classifier.yaml"
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/param
)
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2021-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2021-01-16**:
Thanks for this detailed thoughtful answer!